# Marionette.js template not print completly

Tags: javascript, templates, backbone.js, marionette

`<script id="my-template" type ="text/template"> 
    <div>test</div>

    <%=console.log("ENFIN")%>
    </script>`

Whan i call my template :

```
var myView = new ProfileView({model: myProfile});
myView.render();
```

Only the console log apears and not the  Test

Any ideas?

Thank you very much

Comment: May be i sould re-render my view ?

Comment: Try making a jsFiddle with your issue, so users can see the problem you're talking about (and all of the code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap everything inside the script template with DIV Tag... that will solve your problem

```
<script id = "my-template" type = "text/template"> 
    <div>
         <div>test</div>
         <%=console.log( "ENFIN")%>
    </div>
</script>
```

Comment: I've juste test your answer but it's not changing anyhthing :( Thank you anyway

Comment: are you extending from "Marionette ItemView" ? I assumed you are using Marionette based on the title. If you are using Marionette, you should use Marionette Region to show your views. You don't have to call render directly.

Comment: Thank you! I haven't any region